# Problem with change direction to rtl in Bulma

Tags: frameworks, styles, alignment, direction, bulma

good evening everyone

recently i have use Bulma framework and now i want to try design my theme in RTL mode , I've install all the required thing like bulma rtl and ... , but when i try to use it export that show in browser is like the below image , I've tried use body direction but it doesn't work, and one more thing i use laravel and install all of this with npm
[image]

and here is my code :

```
<nav class="navbar " role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
 <div class="navbar-brand">
  <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
  </a>

  <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data- 
   target="navbarBasicExample">
   <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
 </div>

 <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
  <div class="navbar-start">
    <a class="navbar-item">
      Home
    </a>

   <a class="navbar-item">
    Documentation
   </a>

   <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
    <a class="navbar-link">
      More
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        About
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Jobs
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Contact
      </a>
      <hr class="navbar-divider">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Report an issue
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar-end">
  <div class="navbar-item">
    <div class="buttons">
      <a class="button is-primary">
        <strong>Sign up</strong>
      </a>
      <a class="button is-light">
        Log in
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar is-dark " role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
  <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
  </a>

   <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data- 
    target="navbarBasicExample">
     <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
 </div>

 <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
  <div class="navbar-start">
    <a class="navbar-item">
       Home
   </a>

   <a class="navbar-item">
     Documentation
   </a>

   <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
     <a class="navbar-link">
       More
     </a>

     <div class="navbar-dropdown">
       <a class="navbar-item">
         About
       </a>
       <a class="navbar-item">
         Jobs
       </a>
       <a class="navbar-item">
         Contact
       </a>
       <hr class="navbar-divider">
       <a class="navbar-item">
        Report an issue
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="navbar-end">
   <div class="navbar-item">
     <div class="buttons">
       <a class="button is-primary">
         <strong>Sign up</strong>
       </a>
       <a class="button is-light">
         Log in
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Now [Bulma framework](https://bulma.io) (from version : 0.9.0) supports RTL languages.

You do not need to do anything special.

Just download new version of Bulma and use `Bulma-rtl.css` file.

[Example on codepen](https://codepen.io/avasam/pen/ZEQmEoZ)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

after apply bulma-rtl, you have to make this class and add that to your navbar,navbarBasicExample and navbar-start classes.

```
.flex-direction-row{
    flex-direction: row;
};
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQPxQ.png)

hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using ReactJs**

*Check Bluma framework version . **Your version >= 0.90***

In the Index.js file imports you must use bluma-rtl.min.css :

**By default :**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bulma/css/bulma.min.css';

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root') );
```

**Change to:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bulma/css/bulma-rtl.min.css';

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root') );
```

Answer (score 1):

add `dir="rtl"` to the innermost html tag that includes RTL text
example:

```
<div class="columns is-mobile">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content is-large">

        <p dir="rtl">
          یه متن به زبان فارسی
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```